# Javascript from body to js file

Tags: javascript, xhtml

I am a true rookie in JS, I have this code, in the body of my HTML:

```
  var secDuration = 5;
  var image = 1;
  var maxImages = 4;
  var slider = document.getElementById('slider');

 function changeImage(requiredImage) {


    if (!requiredImage && requiredImage != 0){
      if(image < maxImages){
        image++;
      }
      else{
        image = 1;
      }
    }
    else{ 
      if(requiredImage > maxImages){
        image = 1;
      }
      else if(requiredImage < 1){ 
        image = maxImages;
      }
      else{
        image = requiredImage;
      }
    }
    slider.className = "image"+image;

    clearTimeout(timeout)
  }

  function nextImage(){
    changeImage(image+1);
  }
  function prevImage(){
    changeImage(image-1);
  }

  changeImage(1);
```

The trouble is that when i paste it in a js file which i properly connect to my HTML, the script does not work anymore.
I tried several solutions, but i'm propbably missing something. Help would be gladly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us, how exactly did you do it. Because it has probably not been done properly ;)

Comment: Are you getting an error? Explain a little more by what you mean when you say `"the script does not work anymore"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The valid embedding of JavaScript file is:

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Make sure that your have done in the same way.

Then, you have to work with elements from your HTML page when your page is fully loaded, so move statements like `document.getElementById` in `window.onload` method:

```
window.onload = function() {
    slider = document.getElementById('slider');
};
```

So, your updated script should look like this:

```
var image = 1;
var maxImages = 4;
var slider;

function changeImage(requiredImage) {
    if (!requiredImage && requiredImage != 0) {
        if (image < maxImages) {
            image++;
        }
        else {
            image = 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (requiredImage > maxImages) {
            image = 1;
        }
        else if (requiredImage < 1) {
            image = maxImages;
        }
        else {
            image = requiredImage;
        }
    }
    slider.className = "image" + image;

    clearTimeout(timeout)
}

function nextImage() {
    changeImage(image + 1);
}

function prevImage() {
    changeImage(image - 1);
}

window.onload = function() {
    slider = document.getElementById('slider');
    changeImage(1);
};​
```

Comment: Yes this is what I've done:
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Slider.js"></script>

+ I just modified the last line, but, there is still no movement.

There might be something else

Comment: I'd strongly recommend scripts be loaded at the end of the body if at all possible. See these [best practicies](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) for more information.

Comment: Yes, I just supposed, that it would be more practical for later use to possibly separate the different types of codes, making my site more "organized"

Comment: @jaredhoyt well, millions of flies cannot mistake :)

Comment: @user1376946 please check whether your script has `window.onload` method as described in the updated answer.

Comment: This is It!

Thanks a lot, you made me understand the whole var declaration/initialization in Java.

Your very grateful user1376946